# Bash script that remove duplicates

Tags: bash

This works incorrectly. The script should delete only copies, but this script deletes all files.

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=$1

if [[ -z "$DIR" ]]; then
    echo "Error: files dir is undefined"
fi

files="$( find ${DIR} -type f )"

for file1 in $files; do 
    for file2 in $files; do
        if cmp -s "$file1" "$file2"; then
            rm $file2
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: You must ensure that `[[ $file1 != "$file2" ]]`. Aside: your script won't work if filenames contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/386199/how-to-remove-duplicated-files-in-a-directory) on superuser:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
declare -A arr
shopt -s globstar

for file in **; do
  [[ -f "$file" ]] || continue
   
  read cksm _ < <(md5sum "$file")
  if ((arr[$cksm]++)); then 
    echo "rm $file"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I find answer:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=$1

if [[ -z "$DIR" ]]; then
    echo "Error: files dir is undefined"
fi

files="$( find ${DIR} -type f )"

for file1 in $files; do 
    for file2 in $files; do
        if cmp -s "$file1" "$file2"; then
            rm $file2
        fi
    done
done
```